# AngularJS and jQuery-UI Sortable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am trying to build a very simple angularjs directive that will allow me to nest jquery-ui sortable lists.

I have a pure jquery version that works but when I add in the angularjs directive code it seems to not enable any child elements with the `connectWith` arguement.  Additionally, using the angular version, if I add a dummy `<li>` element in my sub-list jquery seems to recognize it as a list.  I'm not sure what's causing the behavior.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Does not work without `<li>` element in sub-list

http://jsfiddle.net/comamitc/4hAy3/2/

Works with dummy `<li>` element but that element can be moved around and causes confusion.

http://jsfiddle.net/comamitc/4hAy3/3/

Comment: jsfiddle links are both broken

Answer (score 1):

Angular-ui has a ui:sortable directive. You don't need jquery for this to work. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g/hKYWr/)

```
 <ul ui:sortable ng:model="list">
```

Comment: The important piece here is that I should be able to nest them.  I'm no expert in angular-ui but i don't think what you give me can accomplish that... http://jsfiddle.net/comamitc/hKYWr/1337/

Comment: @comamitc, sure it can: http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/1338/
The only thing that won't make you happy is that you still need a "dummy" `<li>` with the `ng-repeat`, but that's just how Angular works.

Comment: As sergey said, you can do nested list with ui:sortable. And I really recommend angular-ui, there are lots of great ui widgets ready for use with angularjs.

Comment: @SergeyK @zszep can  you point me to some documentation?  It doesn't register with my why (in your example) I cannot add Item2 to the List containing `[Item1.A, Item1.B, Item1.C]`.

Comment: @comamitc The documentation can be found at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable